# Scaling text relative to position in browser window.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently stuck on a little bit of math for my project. I'm trying to scale a div in my page based on how close it is to the center of the browser window, so when it is in the center of the window it is full size, but as you scroll down or up it scales down as if to disappear. I'm just struggling on how to calculate this value.

Thanks in advanced,
Harry.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yet? If so, can we see what you've tried so far, with some information on where exactly you're having difficulty?

Comment: I have had a stab at it, but come up with nothing that really works at all. I'm just having trouble calculating the scale value for the div. I want the div the be slightly scaled down to start with then as it comes into view, it should scale up and it get closer to the vertical center of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `x` and `y` be the position of your div relative to the browser window

`window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` will give you the current visible window height and width.

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

The center would be

`var center = (w/2, h/2);`

the distance from the center is:

`var distance = Math.sqrt((w/2 - x)*(w/2 - x), (h/2 - y)*(h/2 - y));`

Now you want to scale the div so that it's maximum size when its distance from the center is 0 and smaller when it's further away.

The simplest thing to do is to use a width of `w - distance` and a height of `h - distance`. That will give you a linear scale, you can use other scaling functions as well, but I'll leave that to you to play with for now. :)